# Does $\mathbb{P}(X\leq5)$ mean $\mathbb{P}(X=0)+..+\mathbb{P}(X=5)$

Tags: probability

Does $\mathbb{P}(X\leq5)$ mean $\mathbb{P}(X=0)+..+\mathbb{P}(X=5)$?

Edit:X ist hypergeometric distributed.

If so, is the following equation correct? 
$1-(\mathbb{P}(X\leq5)-\mathbb{P}(X\leq2))=\\= 1-(\mathbb{P}(X=0)+..+\mathbb{P}(X=5)) - (\mathbb{P}(X=0)+..+\mathbb{P}(X=2))\\=1-(\mathbb{P}(X=3)+..+\mathbb{P}(X=5))\\$

Comment: Is $X$ an integer? Can $X$ be less than zero?

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov Sorry, X ist hypergeometric distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as $X$  folloes the hypergeometric distribution $X$ is a non-negative integer.

Then $\{ \omega: $X$(\omega) \le 5 \} = \bigcup_{i=0}^5 \{ \omega: $X$(\omega) = i \}$. As all the six sets in the R.H.S. are disjoint, the P-measure of their union equals the sum of their P-meausers.